# Two pipes to one command

Tags: bash, shell

I am little bit confused by the following syntax. Although it works, It do not understand why it works. It seems, like there are two pipes attached to the diff command. But isn't there only one `STDIN`?

Examples:

```
diff <(echo "foobar") <(echo "barbaz")
diff <(cat foo.txt) <(cat bar.txt)
```

Comment: Here's a link to the relevant topic--[process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution "process substitution")--in the `bash` man page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The pipes are simply bound to different file descriptors than 0 (stdin):

```
$ echo <(true)
/dev/fd/63
$ echo <(true) <(true)
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
```

A process can of course have more than one open file descriptor at a time, so there's no problem.

Comment: If I only had known its called temporary pipes, I would have been able to google it. Thank you!

Comment: @iblue: I don't think it's called "temporary pipes".  It's just pipes, as created by the `pipe()` system call.

Comment: To be very exact, it might be called "anonymous named pipes", but it is sufficient to google it.

Comment: The process is not started with any additional file descriptors open.  Instead, it is passed the name of a named pipe or some file in /dev/fd.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: As the above examples demonstrate, at least on my Linux box the latter approach is taken.  But "files" in `/dev/fd` are just place holders for file descriptors with the number given in the file name.  Opening a file in `dev/fd` is the same as `dup()`ing the respective file descriptor.

Comment: @sven It is the program that opens the file, and not the shell.  When the program starts, it has only the usual file descriptors open.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: There are no files involved.  The shell creates an anonymous pipe using `pipe()` and then forks the subprocesses. The main process *does* have additional file descriptors open if an anonymous pipe is used.  These additional file descriptors are passed in the form `/dev/fd/...`, and the process will usually simply open them using these file names.  This will lead to them being `dup()`ed, creating even more open file descriptors.  The process could also use the named file descriptor right away without any open calls...

Comment: ...as demonstrated in this [small and stupid test program](https://gist.github.com/1774086).  After compiling to `a`, I called it as `./a <(ls)`, and it successfully printed the list of files, proving the named file decriptor (63 in my case) was already open.  The bash might use named pipes in a temporary directory on different architectures than Linux, in which case no additional file descriptors would be open when entering the main process.